# What is the " batch of results" size in a scroll request

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

**Context**

I have a large index and I want to retrieve all its documents, manipulate them, and then reindex them to another index.

To retrieve all the documents, I'll use the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html)

What I understood is about using that api is:

1. Make a scroll search query to get the *scroll_id*
2. Use that *scroll_id* in each new call to get the next *batch of results*

> Each call to the scroll API returns the next batch of results until there are no more results left to return, ie the hits array is empty.

The value of the *scroll* parameter should be, and I quote:

> . Its value (e.g. 1m) does not need to be long enough to process all data — it just needs to be long enough to process the previous batch of results.

**My question**

What is the size of this **batch of results**?

Is it the [size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) parameter that I have passed in the first scroll API when I got the scroll_id parameter? or something else. The documentation doesn't seem to explain that.

#### Update

Looking at the officially supported Elasticsearch Python client, I can see that there is a [scan function](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.scan). Reading the [Github code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py) for that function (currently starts at line 239), I can find that there is the following call (currently at line 278)

```
resp = client.search(body=query, scroll=scroll, size=size, **kwargs)
```

So the size value is the value passed to the `elasticsearch.helpers.scan` function. However, I tried to make the scan call over my index, passing 100 as the size value, as the following:

```
    es = Elasticsearch([ip address], port= port value)
    results = helpers.scan(es, query={"query": {"match_all": {}}}, scroll=scrollTime, raise_on_error=True, preserve_order=False, size=100, index=my index name)
    numberOfDocument = 0
    for res in results:
        numberOfDocument = numberOfDocument + 1
    print numberOfDocument
```

In the last print statement, I got the total number of documents in my index, not just 100 (though I've passed 100 as the value of the size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

Running this query:

```
GET /_nodes/stats/indices/search?pretty
```

gives many results, one of them is `query_total` field, which indicates the number of queries that the index has received.

That number before running the scan function was 551717, and 552327 after running. The difference is 610. Taking into consideration that running the above `GET` request is also a query so the number of queries becomes `610 - 1 = 609`

The size in the scan function was 100 document. So:

609 * 100 = 60900 document and indeed my index has around 60000 document.

For that I can say that:

1. The `size` in the scan function is the size of the batch.
2. The Python automatically keeps calling scan until there is no more document to fetch.

That's what I could get, looking forward to your verification.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. Just adding the API call to set size in the Java API in case someone else is looking for it:

```
Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(120L));    
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("my-elastic-index");     
searchRequest.scroll(scroll);
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("imageId")));
searchSourceBuilder.size(10000);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```